# How to replace datas inside a curly braces in TCL?

Tags: regex, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have two list in TCL and i want to replace two different curly braces datas with these two list in the same line (Please check the Example ).What type of regular expression or replacement method can be used for this scenario in TCL?Is it possible to use sed command for this case?

```
EXAMPLE 1 :-
 I have to go to park [ -from {orange grey} houses -to {white pink} houses ] 

LIST 1 : set from_bus {red green blue}
LIST 2 : set to_bus {yellow black}

EXPECTED OUTPUT 1 :-
I have to go to park [ -from {red green blue} houses -to {yellow black} houses]
```

```
EXAMPLE 2 :-
 I want fruits [ -from {apple mango} fruits -to {orange banana} fruits ] 

LIST 1 : set from_fruits {grapes watermelon}
LIST 2 : set to_fruits {lime plums}

EXPECTED OUTPUT 2 :-
I want fruits [ -from {grapes watermelon} fruits -to {lime plums} fruits]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do? As it is right now, it looks like you could use [this](https://ideone.com/wzXPom) but you might need something different if there's information you are not mentioning.

Comment: Are we doing replacements by position or by what text is being replaced?

Comment: @Jerry,@Donal Fellows I have two list.In a file,each line having two curly braces with some datas [the same format as mentioned in the example ] and i want to replace two curly braces datas with these two list.First list for first curly brace datas and second list for second curly braces datas.Hope you understand my requirement now.

Comment: @stark Maybe you can provide more examples that are as much different from each other as possible? Something that could go like 'I want this, but if this happens, this is what I want". Basically, I think it's hard to say what is always the same, what is always changing in the problem you are trying to explain.

Comment: @Jerry check the example now and the input format is always same.

Comment: I take it Donal's solution worked then. To me it's still a bit ambiguous because the problem seems simpler than how you are trying to explain it. Could it be you have not written any script/code before?

Comment: @Jerry Yeah Donal's solution worked for my requirement but stil expecting some type of solution using sed command..I explained my requirement and i dont have any script regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace one substring of text by another, we can use a few different techniques. It depends on what you're actually doing. For example, if you want to replace *all* instances of `orange grey` with `red green blue` and all instances of `white pink` with `yellow black`, we use the **string map** command:

```
set mapping [list "orange grey" "red green blue" "white pink" "yellow black"]
set output [string map $mapping $inputText]
```

Doing so by position is a little more complex. Thus, if we are replacing the contents of all `{`braces`}` by index, we instead do this:

```
set replacements [list "red green blue" "yellow black"]
set ranges [regexp -all -inline -indices {\{[^{}]+\}} $inputText]
set lastIndex [expr {min([llength $replacements], [llength $ranges]) - 1}]
set output $inputText
foreach range [lreverse [lrange $ranges 0 $lastIndex]] \
        replacement [lreverse [lrange $replacements 0 $lastIndex]] {
    set repl "{$replacement}"
    set output [string replace $output {*}$range $repl]
}
```

The key trick here is that you're doing the replacements in reverse order (which is why you need to be careful with using `lrange` before `lreverse`) so that the indices still to be replaced are not altered by the replacement.

---

From 8.7 onwards, you'll be able to do this instead:

```
set replacements [list "red green blue" "yellow black"]
set idx -1
set output [regsub -command -all {\{[^{}]+\}} $inputText {apply {- {
    global idx replacements
    string cat "{" [lindex $replacements [incr idx]] "}"
}}}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving such a good solution..First solution worked me but i didn;t understand the code properly.i didn't test second solution yet.Is there any sed command to get the same solution ?

Comment: Can you please explain your code from regexp line ?

Comment: The `regexp` command with the `-all -inline -indices` options returns a list of coordinates (well, indices into the string) in the string where the regular expression matches (i.e., a list of pairs of indices). Then we match up those with the list of replacements and apply them in reverse order (so we don't mess up the indices) to the copy of the input string in the `output` variable; each replacement is done with `string replace`.